# Updating an image in Firebase storage does not work

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I want to update my image in Firebase storage when editing a recipe. But the storagePath.delete() method does not work. It throws the following error:

> [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference)

Is there a solution to this problem, or maybe just another way to replace an image that I don't know about?

```
 Map<String, dynamic> initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'ingredients': [''],
    'steps': [''],
    'imageUrl': '',
    'creatorId': '',
    'p': '',
    'c': '',
    'f': '',
    'kcal': '',
    'servings': '',
    'id': '',
  };

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final String? recipeId =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;
    if (recipeId != null) {
      newRecipe = functions.findById(recipeId);
      initValues = {
        'title': newRecipe.title,
        'description': newRecipe.description,
        'ingredients': newRecipe.ingredients,
        'steps': newRecipe.steps,
        'imageUrl': newRecipe.imageUrl,
        'creatorId': newRecipe.creatorId,
        'p': newRecipe.p.toString(),
        'c': newRecipe.c.toString(),
        'f': newRecipe.f.toString(),
        'kcal': newRecipe.kcal.toString(),
        'servings': newRecipe.servings.toString(),
        'id': recipeId,
      };
      newRecipe.id = recipeId;
    }

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _descriptionNode.dispose();
    _ingredientsNode.dispose();
    _instructionsNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> saveData() async {
    bool isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    if (isValid == true) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      final storagePath = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('recipe_image')
          .child(newRecipe.id + '.jpg');
      if (initValues['id'] != '') {
        storagePath.delete();
      }
      await storagePath.putFile(pickedImage);
      final imageUrl = await storagePath.getDownloadURL();
      newRecipe.imageUrl = imageUrl;

      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(NutritionScreen.routeName, arguments: {
        'title': newRecipe.title,
        'description': newRecipe.description,
        'ingredients': newRecipe.ingredients,
        'steps': newRecipe.steps,
        'imageUrl': newRecipe.imageUrl,
        'creatorId': newRecipe.creatorId,
        'p': newRecipe.p,
        'c': newRecipe.c,
        'f': newRecipe.f,
        'kcal': newRecipe.kcal,
        'servings': newRecipe.servings,
        'id': newRecipe.id,
      });
    }
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

 Future<void> editRecipe(Recipe newRecipe) async {
    final recipeIndex =
        _recipes.indexWhere((element) => element.id == newRecipe.id);
    if (recipeIndex >= 0) {
      final url = Uri.parse(
          'https://recipier-e1139-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/recipes/${newRecipe.id}.json');
      try {
        await http.patch(
          url,
          body: json.encode(
            {
              'title': newRecipe.title,
              'description': newRecipe.description,
              'ingredients': newRecipe.ingredients,
              'steps': newRecipe.steps,
              'kcal': newRecipe.kcal,
              'p': newRecipe.p,
              'c': newRecipe.c,
              'f': newRecipe.f,
              'servings': newRecipe.servings,
              'imageUrl': newRecipe.imageUrl,
              'creatorId': userId,
            },
          ),
        );
        _recipes[recipeIndex] = newRecipe;
      } catch (error) {
        rethrow;
      }
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: As Evgen answered below, I recommend running the code in a debugger and checking what the path is that you call `delete()` on. Storage is unlikely to be wrong about no object existing at that path, so more likely there's a difference between the path you build in your code, and where the file exists on the Storage servers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your problem with debugger https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/debugger
Check how your editRecipe function works.